# How can I use SSH to tunnel Minecraft clients to my MineOS server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, turnkey, minecraft

I have a MineOS Turnkey server running on my university's network and its locked behind their firewall. I have been able to connect to their Linux servers using SSH and then SSH to my server from there, however, I don't know how to tunnel the connection from a Minecraft client on my computer to the server I have double SSHed to. While on their network I can easily connect to the server; however, as I'm on break, I don't have direct access to the network.

Comment: Just discovered that Bucknell provides a VPN service that works beautifully and technically the problem is solved. However, I still don't know how to work with tunneling and if someone would fill me in theoretically, that would be awesome. Also, the VPN fix doesn't work for non-Bucknell students and I do have others who would like to join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be related to this question https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/how-can-i-play-minecraft-through-a-proxy-server

You can either port forward or create a SOCKS proxy. Check `ssh -L` or `ssh -D` in the SSH manual.

If port forwarding you have to use `localhost` as the Minecraft server address. For SOCKS proxy, check out `--proxyHost` and `--proxyPort` as an argument when running the JAR file. Hints from http://hydra.geht.net/tino/howto/software/minecraft/proxy/

> ```
> Download minecraft.jar (this is Minecraft for Linux) and run it as follows:
>
> java -Dhttp.proxyHost=PROXYHOST -Dhttp.proxyPort=PROXYPORT -Dhttps.proxyHost=PROXYHOST -Dhttps.proxyPort=PROXYPORT -jar d:\minecraft\minecraft.jar --proxyHost SOCKSHOST --proxyPort SOCKSPORT
>
> Replace following words above with:
> PROXYHOST: your HTTP proxy IP 
> PROXYPORT: is your HTTP proxy port, usually 8080 
> SOCKSHOST: is your SOCKS5 proxy IP 
> SOCKSPORT: is your SOCKS5 proxy port, usually 1080
> ```